# How to Schedule a scheduler to run at multiple time intervals

Tags: java, scheduling, executorservice

I have a scheduler which runs after every five minutes. I want to run this scheduler after every 1 hour also. I want same scheduler to run at two different times periodically.

```
 ScheduledExecutorService scheduledThreadPool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        scheduledThreadPool.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            public void run() 
              {
              }, 0, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

I am writing this way which runs after every 5 minutes. Now i want the same scheduler to run every 1 hour also.

Comment: as 60/5 = 12 your scheduler will run every hour.

Comment: Yes i want to run it after every 1 hour again for cleanup purpose

Comment: It already is running each hour, because it runs every 5 minutes. Unless you want to run something different each hour?

Answer (score 0):

Running a task every five minutes means your task is also running every hour. After 12 runs, an hour will have elapsed. So every twelfth run is an hour apart. 12 * 5 minutes = 60 minutes = 1 hour.

If you have a *different* task to run every hour, call a `scheduledAt…` method again on your `ScheduledExecutorService` object.

```java
Runnable runnableA = new Runnable() { public void run() {…} ; }
Runnable runnableB = new Runnable() { public void run() {…} ; }

ScheduledExecutorService scheduledThreadPool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

scheduledThreadPool.scheduleAtFixedRate( runnableA , 0 , 5 , TimeUnit.MINUTES );
scheduledThreadPool.scheduleAtFixedRate( runnableB , 0 , 1 , TimeUnit.HOURS );
```